# cannot move out of dereference

Tags: json, rust

I'm learning Rust as well as the extra::json module. Here is my example (with extra unneeed type annotations):

```
let j:Result<Json,JsonError> = from_str("[{\"bar\":\"baz\", \"biz\":123}]");
let l:List = match j {
  Ok(List(l)) => l,
  Ok(_) => fail!("Expected a list at the top level"),
  Err(e) => fail!(fmt!("Error: %?", e))
};
println(fmt!("item = %?", l.iter().advance(|i|{
  match i {
      &Object(o) => {
          println(fmt!("Object is %?", o));
      },
      _ => {
          fail!("Should be a list of objects, no?");
      }
  }
  println(fmt!("i=%?", i));
  true
})));
```

When I compile, I get this:

```
$ rust run json.rs
json.rs:70:9: 70:18 error: cannot move out of dereference of & pointer
json.rs:70         &Object(o) => {
                    ^~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of fmt!
json.rs:68:10: 79:6 note: expansion site
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have [other examples](https://github.com/ozten/learning_rust/blob/master/play/json.rs) of using match that don't hit this error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Patterns like that are destructuring, which means they move out of the thing they match on by default. You want:

```
&Object(ref o) => { ... }
```

Which takes a borrowed reference to the member, rather than moving out of it.

Comment: Thanks for this concise solution and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Corey's answer is much better. For discussion / completeness I thought I would add what I found before reading his answer.

You can get rid of the `&` by doing this:

```
let item:Json = copy *i;
    match item {
        Object(o) => {
            println(fmt!("true = %?", o.contains_key(&~"bar")));
            //let barItem = ;
            let baz = match copy *o.get(&~"bar") {
                String(abaz) => abaz,
                _ => fail!("Expected bar property")
            };
            println(fmt!("bar = %?", baz));
```

It is not as good as the `ref` solution, because you copy the JSON object and use more memory.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
   match *i {
      Object(ref o) => println(fmt!("Object is %?", o)),
      _ => fail!("Should be a list of objects, no?")
   }
```

see https://github.com/mozilla/rust/wiki/Note-style-guide#match-expressions